# How to convert a Java Date object into a JRuby Time object?

Tags: jruby

Using JRuby, is there a good way to convert a Java Date object into a JRuby Time object?  I'm using the latest version of JRuby (1.3.1) and Java SE 6.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This should work fine:

```
Time.at(java.util.Date.new.getTime/1000)
```

Comment: And the reverse: java.util.Date.new(Time.now.to_i*1000)